# Using PHP, How to create a function that validates the name in html form

Tags: php

I am trying to validate a html form using php. But I'm having a hard time since our professor provided us a pre coded activity.

So, his code is like this.

```
if(isset($_POST['save'])){
        //sanitize user inputs
        $firstname = htmlentities($_POST['fn']);
        $lastname = htmlentities($_POST['ln']);
        $email = htmlentities($_POST['email']);
        $status = 'Inactive';
        if(isset($_POST['status'])){
            $status = $_POST['status'];
        }
        $faculty = array(
            "firstname" => $firstname,
            "lastname" => $lastname,
            "email" => $email,
            "academic_rank" => $_POST['rank'],
            "department" => $_POST['department'],
            "admission_role" => $_POST['role'],
            "status" => $status
        );
        array_push($_SESSION['faculty'], $faculty);

        //redirect user to faculty page after saving
        header('location: faculty.php');
    }

?>
```

this is where the form will be saved, as for the html form. I Did not wrote the whole code as it is the same.

```
         <label for="fn">First Name</label>
         <input type="text" id="fn" name="fn" required placeholder="Enter first name">
                           
         <input type="submit" class="button" value="Save Faculty" name="save" id="save">
```

I am trying to learn php...Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly do you want to validate? The length of the name, that it contains only a-z chars, etc. ?

Comment: only the length of the name, so for example, if user enter a number instead of letter it will shows an error like "Please enter a Valid name".

Comment: @Bin-bazAkilan you want to show the error on submit button click or on typing ?

Comment: _"only the length of the name, so for example, if user enter a number instead of letter it will shows an error like "Please enter a Valid name"."_ - so you do _not_ want to just check the length then. Maybe you should clarify your actual requirements first. And then - do some research; you are likely _not_ the first person ever trying to solve such a task.

Comment: on the submit button click, so like the form will not submit if the user input a name and it will show error.

Comment: If you want the checks to be carried out without the form being "submit" then you will have to check in JavaScript or in PHP but via AJAX

Comment: Tip: validate on the way _in_, escape on the way _out_: you don't want to store the version that's been run through `htmlentities` - maybe later you'll decide to include it in a plain-text e-mail, or generated image; instead, you should call `htmlentities` when _display something in HTML context_, i.e. when using `echo` onto an HTML page.

Comment: Consider reading https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/ before validating names. People have very unusual names surprisingly often. I personally have a dash in my last name, and it's infurating when websites tell me it's not valid.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this one

```
 if(isset($_POST['save'])){
    if (preg_match('~[0-9]+~', $_POST['fn']) || preg_match('~[0-9]+~', $_POST['ln'])) {
        // show error like "please enter valid name", or whatever you want
    }else{
        $firstname = htmlentities($_POST['fn']);
        $lastname = htmlentities($_POST['ln']);
        $email = htmlentities($_POST['email']);
        $status = 'Inactive';
        if(isset($_POST['status'])){
            $status = $_POST['status'];
        }
        $faculty = array(
            "firstname" => $firstname,
            "lastname" => $lastname,
            "email" => $email,
            "academic_rank" => $_POST['rank'],
            "department" => $_POST['department'],
            "admission_role" => $_POST['role'],
            "status" => $status
        );
        array_push($_SESSION['faculty'], $faculty);

        //redirect user to faculty page after saving
        header('location: faculty.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: It works but I need to delete the htmlentities. How can I add without deleting a code?

Comment: "I need to delete the htmlentities" - whatever that means, it should be part of your question if others should use this requirement

Comment: @Bin-bazAkilan  I just explained about the logic only rest you have to use according to your requirement. 
I'm agree with "NicoHaase" others can explain things , you are going to be a developer then you have to know how to use the explained logics and code.
anyways modified my answer , check now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use validator like this. This will check have you sent fn or not.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                        'fn'    =>  'required',
    
                    ]);
    
            if ($validator->fails()) {
                        
                        return back();
            }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Where does that `Validator` class come from? Vanilla PHP does not ship it